# Postgresql trigger function with concatenate not working

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers, concatenation

I'm new to trigger functions and PostgreSQL, and I'm trying create a calculated field combining other fields (I know that this might violate the normal forms, but I'm working with a pre-existing naming convention). The goal is to have the `animal_id` field be created at insertion or update of records and look like "ANAM-2011-10". I have tried two different ways to insert a concatenated string, and each has their own issues. Here's the table:

```
CREATE TABLE capt_trial
(animal_id VARCHAR(15),
species CHAR(4),
capture_year SMALLINT,
tag_num NUMERIC,
tag_col CHAR(1));
```

**Scenario #1:** using `SET` field `=` concatenated string in function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_short_animal_id_1()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    SET NEW.animal_id = CONCAT(species, '-', capture_year, '-', tag_num);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;
```

This is the error message when trying to create the function:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 7:  SET NEW.animal_id = CONCAT(species, '-', capture_year, '-',...
                                   ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 125
```

**Scenario #2:** using `INSERT INTO` field `VALUES` concatenated string in function. The function and the trigger were created successfully.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_short_animal_id_2()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO capt_trial(animal_id) 
    VALUES(CONCAT(species, '-', capture_year, '-', tag_num));
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;


CREATE TRIGGER trigger_create_short_animal_id_2
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON public."capt_trial"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_short_animal_id_2();
```

But when I tried to insert values into the table:

```
INSERT INTO capt_trial (species, capture_year, tag_num, tag_col)
VALUES ('ANAM', 2011, 10, 'B'),
       ('ANAM', 2012, 142, 'Y'),
       ('OVCA', 2013, 137, NULL),
       ('ODHE', 2014, 75, NULL);
```

I got this error:

```
ERROR:  column "species" does not exist
LINE 2:  VALUES(CONCAT(species, '-', capture_year, '-', tag_num))
                       ^
HINT:  There is a column named "species" in table "capt_trial", but it cannot be referenced 
from this part of the query.
QUERY:  INSERT INTO capt_trial(animal_id) 
        VALUES(CONCAT(species, '-', capture_year, '-', tag_num))
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function create_short_animal_id() line 3 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42703
```

Does anyone know what the issue is with the syntax or how to get this to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first example do:

`NEW.animal_id = CONCAT(NEW.species, '-', NEW.capture_year, '-', NEW.tag_num)`

You are assigning to the `NEW.animal_id` not setting anything. FYI, `:=` can also be used for assignment.

Comment: With before trigger can we use NEW?

Comment: Yes it all spelled out here [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html). Using `BEFORE` trigger is the only way you can modify the `NEW.aninmal_id` as an `AFTER` trigger does not return anything.

Comment: Thanks noted. I again read the documentation your right.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_short_animal_id_2()
RETURNS trigger
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    NEW.animal_id := concat(NEW.species,'-',NEW.capture_year)
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$;


CREATE TRIGGER trigger_create_short_animal_id_2
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON public."capt_trial"
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE create_short_animal_id_2
```

You can use above draft trigger and func to have your result.NEW- record in new result, OLD - record before trigger function.

Comment: This is not going two work as: 1)  `RETURN NEW` is ignored in an `AFTER` trigger 2) The OP wants `CONCAT(species, '-', capture_year, '-', tag_num)` not `concat(OLD.species,'-',OLD.capture_year)`. 3) You want the `NEW` values not the `OLD` in order to capture the changes.

Comment: Yeah you are right. Thanks. I will cotrect it.